CSS not applied to Flask webapp when I host it with Firebase Hosting
Description
I'm currently using Firebase Hosting to deploy my Flask web app and all of them are working well except when I click the link provided from Firebase, it only shows the HTML file without any CSS and JavaScript applied.
Directory Structure

Expected Behavior
All HTML, CSS, and JS files working well as it was when I ran it locally like the image below.

Current Behavior



const promptInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
const chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatContainer");
const typingIndicator = document.getElementById("typingIndicator");
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
const sidebarContent = document.getElementById("sidebarContent");
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");

async function sendMessage() {
  const prompt = promptInput.value.trim();
  if (!prompt && imageContainer.children.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a message or add an image.");  // Browser pop up message
    return;
  }

  // Collect image data
  const images = Array.from(imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview'))
    .map(img => img.src.split(',')[1]); // Extract base64 data

  addMessage(prompt, 'user', images);
  promptInput.value = "";

  showTypingIndicator();

  const generatedText = await generateText(prompt, images);
  addMessage(generatedText, 'bot');

  hideTypingIndicator();
  //clearImagePreviews(); Add this code if you want the image in the imageContainer disappear if the user sends the image.
}

async function generateText(prompt, images) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/generate_text_stream", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ prompt, images }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error("Error:", response.statusText);
      return "Error occurred while generating response.";
    }

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let isFinished = false;
    let generatedTextContent = "";

    while (!isFinished) {
      const { done, value } = await reader.read();
      if (done) {
        isFinished = true;
        break;
      }
      generatedTextContent += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
    }

    return generatedTextContent;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return "An error occurred.";
  }
}

function addMessage(text, type, images = []) {
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.className = `message ${type}`;

  const messageContent = document.createElement("div");
  messageContent.className = "message-bubble fadeIn";
  messageContent.innerHTML = `<p>${text}</p>`;

  images.forEach(src => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${src}`;
    img.classList.add("message-image");
    messageContent.appendChild(img);
  });

  messageDiv.appendChild(messageContent);
  chatContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
  chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
}

function clearImagePreviews() {
  while (imageContainer.firstChild) {
    imageContainer.removeChild(imageContainer.firstChild);
  }
  checkImageContainerVisibility();
}

let typingTimeout;

function showTypingIndicator() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
  typingIndicator.style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideTypingIndicator() {
  typingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    typingIndicator.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000);
}

function handleKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    sendMessage();
  }
}

function toggleSidebar() {
  if (sidebar.style.width === "500px") {
    sidebar.style.width = "0";
    sidebarContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "500px";
    sidebarContent.style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onload = () => addMessage("Hello! How can I assist you today?", 'bot');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('userInput');

  textInput.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    const items = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).items;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
        const file = item.getAsFile();
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          displayImage(event.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

  function displayImage(src) {
    const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
    imgContainer.classList.add('img-preview-container');

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.classList.add('img-preview');

    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.classList.add('remove-button');
    removeButton.textContent = '✖';
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      imgContainer.remove();
      checkImageContainerVisibility();
    });

    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
    imgContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
    imageContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);
    checkImageContainerVisibility();

    const all_images = imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview-container');
    all_images.forEach(img => img.style.width = `${100 / all_images.length - 10}%`);
  }

  function checkImageContainerVisibility() {
    if (imageContainer.children.length > 0) {
      imageContainer.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      imageContainer.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }

  // Initial check to hide image container if empty
  checkImageContainerVisibility();
});
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f0f2f5;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

/* Generate report button styling */
button, input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

/* Form styling */
form {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}

select, input[type="submit"] {
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
}

select {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Report page styling */
.report-container {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow: auto;
}

a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Section that will show report content */
.report-content {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.report-content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    height: 600px;
}



/* Chat Bot */
.container {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.chat {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

.message {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.message.user {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.message-bubble {
    padding: 12px 18px;
    max-width: 70%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
}

.message.user .message-bubble {
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
}

.message.bot .message-bubble {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    color: #333;
}


.message-image {
    max-width: 100px; /* Set the maximum width for the image */
    max-height: 100px; /* Set the maximum height for the image */
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover; /* Ensures the image retains its aspect ratio */
}


input[type="text"] {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
}

.send-button {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.send-button:hover {
    background-color: #2c5282;
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #666;
    position: static;
    border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadeIn {
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 10px auto 0;
    }

    .chat {
        height: 300px;
    }

    .input-container {
        max-width: 95%;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    .send-button {
        padding: 10px 14px;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .footer {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}

.typing-indicator {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 4px;
    animation: typing 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0%,
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
}

/* Side bar */
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar-content {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-content h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-content p {
    padding: 10px;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button:hover {
    background-color: #2c5282;
}

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    width: 100%;
    /*padding: 12px 18px;*/

    overflow: hidden;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*border: 1px solid #444;*/
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.img-preview-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 15%;
}

.img-preview {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.remove-button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.remove-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio Backtesting</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('public/static', filename='css/style.css') }}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Portfolio Backtesting</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/">
      <label for="cs_model">Choose Cross-Sectional Model:</label>
      <select id="cs_model" name="cs_model">
        <option value="EW">Equal Weight (EW)</option>
        <option value="MSR">Maximum Sharpe Ratio (MSR)</option>
        <option value="GMV">Global Minimum Variance (GMV)</option>
        <option value="MDP">Minimum Drawdown Risk (MDP)</option>
        <option value="EMV">Equal Risk Contribution (EMV)</option>
        <option value="RP">Risk Parity (RP)</option>
      </select>

      <label for="ts_model">Choose Time-Series Model:</label>
      <select id="ts_model" name="ts_model">
        <option value="VT">Volatility Targeting (VT)</option>
        <option value="CVT">Conditional Value at Risk Targeting (CVT)</option>
        <option value="KL">Kelly Criterion (KL)</option>
        <option value="CPPI">
          Constant Proportion Portfolio Insurance (CPPI)
        </option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
    </form>

    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <button class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleSidebar()">☰</button>
      <div class="sidebar-content" id="sidebarContent">
        <div class="container bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
          <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4 text-center">ChatBot</h1>
          <div class="chat" id="chatContainer"></div>
          <div class="image-container hidden" id="imageContainer"></div>
          <div class="flex">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="userInput"
              placeholder="Type your message here..."
              class="outline-none"
              onkeyup="handleKeyPress(event)"
            />
            <button class="send-button" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
          </div>
          <div class="typing-indicator" id="typingIndicator"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('public/static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>



